# Counting the number of certain characters in a string

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and since my first computer language is Python, I don't really understand what I did wrong here.

The purpose of this code is to find out how many certain alphabets are included in a string of length 8, but I keep getting the following error:

> ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int cnt = 0;
    string temp;
    cin >> temp; // the input string will be of length 8
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (temp[i] == "F") {
            cnt += 1;
        };
    };
    cout << cnt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I print out `temp[i]` in the code, I can confirm that `temp[i]` is printed out as a single character, which I believe can be compared with another character, in this case the character `"F"`.

I've been trying to find out why this is happening, but ended up coming here to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (temp[i] == "F") {` should be `if (temp[i] == 'F') {`.

- `'F'` is a character (`char`)
- `"F"` is a C-string (`const char[2]` which decays to `const char*`).

Comment: Wow never thought C++ conceives "" and '' differently as they are literally the same in Python...

Comment: Different languages, so different conventions/rules.

Comment: @James "*they are literally the same in Python*" - that is because Python doesn't have a dedicated single-character type, only a string type. So it can support both single-quote and double-quote syntaxes for string literals (many scripts languages do). C/C++, on the other hand, have separate types for single-characters and strings, so single-quote and double-quote are handled differently.

Comment: @James: Notice that you can directly use `auto cnt = std::count(temp.begin(), temp.end(), 'F');`